# iterate a 3 level nested array and pick the values of the inner array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Using Javascript I'm trying to loop through a 3 level nested array with the following structure:

```
Coordinates=[
             [
               [21.65568722694544, -21.69807092918915],
               [21.60654489773522, -21.69898151401483], 
               [21.55814494317222, -21.6948413352827], 
            ],
            [
               [31.25568722694544, -51.76895092918915],
               [31.40654489773522, -51.65698151401483], 
               [31.55814494317222, -51.5438413352827], 
            ],

          ]
```

I need to extract the X and Y values of the inner array.
Is there a way to get the following structure from the array:

```
polylines=      [
    new google.maps.LatLng( 35.0041, -88.1955 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 34.9918, -85.6068 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 32.8404, -85.1756 )

  ],
  [
    new google.maps.LatLng( 41.0037, -104.0556 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 44.9949, -104.0584 ),
    new google.maps.LatLng( 44.9998, -111.0539 )

  ]
];

          ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i=0;i<Coordinates.length;i++) {
    var the3Coords = Coordinates[i];

    for (var j=0;j<the3Coords.length;j++) {
        var xyCoord = the3Coords[j];

        // x = xyCoord[0];
        // y = xyCoord[1];
    }
}
```

You can see this in action here; http://jsfiddle.net/h7J2N/

I've used the variables to make it easier to see where you are in the program; you can of course do away with the variables if you wanted;

```
for (var i=0;i<Coordinates.length;i++) {
    for (var j=0;j<Coordinates[i][j].length;j++) { 

        // x = Coordinates[i][j][0];
        // y = Coordinates[i][j][1];

    }
}
```

For what it's worth, a variable name with a leading capital is, [by convention](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html), normally reserved for constructor functions. As such, you might want to consider using `coordinates` over `Coordinates` as your variable name (and yes, [JavaScript is case sensitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Case_sensitivity)).